# Preserve data AngularJS after refreshing

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

This is my situation: I have a web application, frontend written in AngularJS/HTML.

For the moment, I have 2 views (2 different HTML - pages).

I enter in the first view a serial number, which is passed on from the first controller to the controller of the 2nd view with the help of a service.

At the second view, I display some json-data, obtained from a Django API endpoint. When I refresh the page, this data is gone and the fields are empty...

In my case, this is not so user friendly, so I want to preserve the data (or serial number I pass on in the controller) to retrieve back the data or serial number after refreshing. Because after refreshing, the variable (the serial number) will be null in my service, so the json call will fail.

I've red many things on the internet already, but nothing is actually working for me. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: You can use localStorage to save your serial number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your second view is dependent on a value, this value could be the param for your view url, instead of sharing it through service. Pass on the param using either angular ui-router or built in ngRoute.
Here are helpful links:

1. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing
2. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $cookieStore service in angular and store the value in a cookie in the first controller, and get the value in the second controller.

$cookieStore.put("key", "value");

In, the second controller do,

$cookieStore.get("key");